# How do I use a Bibulous referencing style in my document?

Tags: texworks, bibulous

I use TexWorks on windows 11, I am getting increasingly confused about any other detail.

My ultimate aim is to create a reference list in a custom style, and I've spent hours now trying to strategise the best way to do that. My current idea is to write the custom style in the format that works with Bibulous, and use that in my document. Please let me know if I've picked out a painful method to start with.

To that end, I am trying to make the absolute minimum example work with Bibulous before I move on to writing my custom one. I have been trying to get [example 1](https://github.com/nzhagen/bibulous/tree/master/examples) from the Bibulous documentation to work on my computer, and I can't. In my latest attempt, the pdf compiles with no references, and the log tells me all my references were undefined. everything is named as it is on the repo, I am not sure where I went wrong with it.

thank you very much, I'm quite frustrated with it at the moment

edit: possibly an improvement: still no concept behind what I'm doing, but I have successfully compiled with references. I needed to compile with TexWorks, then use python from my command line to run the bibulous.py file on the *.aux file, and then run TexWorks twice. Some issues with formatting but a big step forward. thanks again.

Comment: I never heard of it before, typically users use either bibtex or biblatex/biber. And from the github it doesn't look as if there is much happening. But perhaps this issue helps you: https://github.com/nzhagen/bibulous/issues/16

Comment: i got really very lost in trying to write a style with classic bibtex, have you written a custom style using bibtex or biblatex/biber before?

Comment: I never wrote a bibtex style, but I have adapted a few biblatex styles. But in my opinion there are now so many various biblatex styles that there is seldom the need to spent much time on writing another one unless you have really special requirements.

Comment: it's a stipulation for this university task that we use a specific journal's referencing style, and though I found an endnote style file, I couldn't find a .bst. Do you have any tips on finding bst files around? I sent the journal an email but thats a longshot. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexRussell, if you click on tag "bibulous" you'll find some examples https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibulous. // If biblatex is confusing, why not using Zotero and its plugin better-bibtex? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zotero // Zotero: https://www.zotero.org/

Comment: Are you able to ask or examine, as a resource, previous cohorts' output to see how they did it, presuming you are not first generation? Rather than reinventing the wheel. Unrelated: bst files are beyond my understanding, but biblatex/biber can read bibtex databases (the .bib file) and I create the db by copy-pasting from a spreadsheet which creates the right format using its built-in substitute and concatenate functions. Depends on your coding/process/toolkit ecosystem, I suppose.

Comment: thanks all, I have a vaguely working set up now, but it does feel somewhat fragile. @MS-SPO thanks for mentioning, when this breaks I'll look into that, I didn't realise they had such a plug in. Thanks again.